# Supplying the /installas command line parameter requires that vsixinstaller is run as admin

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hello I am installing Microsoft Reporting Services Projects through Extensions & Updates  but I am getting an error saying the following

---

### VSIX Installer

### Supplying the /installas command line parameter requires that vsixinstaller is run as admin.

### OK

I tried to installed by directly but it is not letting do more than download an extension for vs code which I am not using at all, I tried to find it in through the Extension and updates in vs 2017 but It is not there.

can you help me with this